# Google maps displays many versions of same map upon zooming out

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to zoom out of the google map,this is what happens:[image]

How can I stop this kind of behaviour from occuring?

Comment: This is how Google default map is designed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the **minZoom** property in your map options:

```
...
var mapOptions = {
    minZoom: 2
}

map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map-canvas' ), mapOptions );
...
```

This will limit the amount that user will be able to zoom out, which will prevent the map from repeating.

More info: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Comment: Setting both the minZoom and zoom to 4 kinda works but scrolling right from Australia(where the map is centered) takes you to South America.The user probably wont be expecting this.And I cant scroll back to see multiple continents

Answer (score 0):

Set maxZoom property for map .

```
var mapOptions = {
                 zoom: 11,
                 center: tokyo,
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
 }

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', showMaxZoom);
```

Look at here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom